# footnote function from kableExtra in R returns LateX error: multicol in Rmd file while knitting it to a PDF

Tags: latex, r-markdown, kableextra, multicol

I was using ***footnote*** function of ***kableExtra*** package to write a footnote  on a table, but I get the following LaTeX error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mulicol.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.126 

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Ejecución interrumpida
```

The code that I am running is:

````
---
output:
pdf_document:
  toc: yes
  toc_depth: 5
  keep_tex: yes
html_document:
  theme: united
  toc: yes
classoption: table
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{mulicol}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results='asis'}
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE) 
require(kableExtra)
cat(kable(head(cars),"latex",digits=c(1,1), longtable =TRUE,row.names=FALSE, 
caption = "Descriptive analysis for the")%>%footnote(general= "Repeatability 
(%CV) = ")
      )
```
````

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurs for many LaTeX packages, where the error message is always:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `packagename.sty' not found.
```

For your case need to download the multicol package from [ctan.org](https://ctan.org/), unzip it and upload *multicol.sty* to the same directory your Rmd document is in.

Props go to [this answer on the TeX stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152281).

EDIT:

For the multicol package, another step is needed. See the README of the multicol package once downloaded.